# How to use React Native PixelRatio utility class?

Tags: react-native, pixel-ratio

I have an app written initially for iPhone 6 symulator which has a componend syled with following example values:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerNav: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40
  },
  headerLogoImage: {
    width: 140,
    height: 140
  },
  footerNavText: {
    padding: 15,
    fontSize: 25
  }
});
```

Unfortunately when I launched the app on iPad symulator, the size proportions completely collapsed. I know that there is something like PixelRation but documentation is very limited and unclear.

Any idea / suggestions how can I translate these width / height / padding & fontSize to proper values using this PixelRatio class?

Answer (score 4):

fontSize needs to be divided by `PixelRatio.getFontScale()`. This will account for different screen densities in iOS and Android.

```
footerNavText: {
  fontSize: 25 / PixelRatio.getFontScale()
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html

Comment: See doc, only supports Android

Comment: @James On the current doc, there is no mentioning of this being supported only for Android. Can you update your comment so that it doesn't confuse someone else besides myself?

Comment: @milut.in getFontScale is supported as of 2024-02-28T14:47:59Z on both platforms

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
footerNavText: {
  padding: PixelRatio.get()*3,
  fontSize: PixelRatio.get()*4
}
```

Check what get() method returns for each of the devices you wish to use and style accordingly.
For more info visit https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html

Answer (score 2):

```js
// create this utils.ts file
import { PixelRatio } from "react-native";

// dp(123) converts 123px (px as in your mockup design) to dp.
export const dp = (px: number) => {
    return px / PixelRatio.get();
};

// sp(54) converts 54px (px as in your mockup design) to sp
export const sp = (px: number) => {
    return px / (PixelRatio.getFontScale() * PixelRatio.get());
};
```

Use it like the following way in your styles

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footerNavText: {
    padding: dp(123),
    fontSize: sp(54)
  }
})
```

> **Note**
>
> Do not use dp for `fontSize`. dp just depends on device screen density (dpi)
>
> sp is used for `fontSize` only. sp is also just like dp but the difference is that it also depends on user's font settings in his device along with the device screen density (dpi).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { PixelRatio } from "react-native";

// Testing phone's pixel density as base
const basePixelDensity = 2.8125
const baseFontScale = 1.2

export const sp = (px: number) => {
  // the higher the font scaling the more we divided by it
  // the higher the pixel density compare to our base pixel density, the more we increase font size (or decrease if the pixel density is lower)
  return px / ((PixelRatio.getFontScale() / baseFontScale) * basePixelDensity) * (PixelRatio.get() / basePixelDensity);
};
```

Set your own base density and font scale, worked for me